# User interface design tool

Tags: tools, user-interface, ui

Are there any applications that can help me design a user interface in conceptual way?

Comment: Like a mock up or rough drawing or are you looking for something to assist in best practices and design principles?

Comment: Try justinmind prototyper. You can literally see how your interface will look and work.

Comment: If you are using Firefox, Pencil may be an option: http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a mockup tool? If so then I can recommend [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups)

With this you can create a mockup of your page which *looks* like it has been drawn, so when you show it to other people (preferably your potential users) they don't have the expectation that it will do anything when they try.

Comment: Yep I've only used Balsamiq and it is pretty good. I've used it as part of been inbuilt to JIRA (Atlassian). Gets the job done in simple fashion (mock ups I have created so far).

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a Microsoft space [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/sketchflow_overview.aspx) is relatively new and might be for you.

I Do believe that [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) is the defacto standard, most used and most mature.

I haven't used either yet but the video's I have seen make me think [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/sketchflow_overview.aspx) is more for graphical designers than for developers.

Some nice thoughts on how [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/sketchflow_overview.aspx) and [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) compare can be found [here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/2e18ea28-ff44-4732-8036-d36c074735c6) and [here](http://www.elucidsoft.com/blog/2010/02/16/balsamiq-mockups-vs-microsoft-sketchflow/)

If neither is good for you a nice list of GUI Prototyping tools can be found [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools)